# How to detect if a field contains a character in Lua

Tags: lua

I'm trying to modify an existing lua script that cleans up subtitle data in Aegisub.

I want to add the ability to delete lines that contain the symbol "♪"

Here is the code I want to modify:

```
-- delete commented or empty lines
function noemptycom(subs,sel)
    progress("Deleting commented/empty lines")
    noecom_sel={}
    for s=#sel,1,-1 do
        line=subs[sel[s]]
        if line.comment or line.text=="" then
        for z,i in ipairs(noecom_sel) do noecom_sel[z]=i-1 end
        subs.delete(sel[s])
        else
        table.insert(noecom_sel,sel[s])
        end
    end
    return noecom_sel
end
```

I really have no idea what I'm doing here, but I know a little SQL and LUA apparently uses the IN keyword as well, so I tried modifying the IF line to this

```
        if line.text in (♪) then
```

Needless to say, it didn't work. Is there a simple way to do this in LUA? I've seen some threads about the string.match() & string.find() functions, but I wouldn't know where to start trying to put that code together. What's the easiest way for someone with zero knowledge of Lua?

Comment: the in keyword is only meant for for-loops, like "for i,value in pairs(aTable) do ... end"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`in` is only used in the generic for loop. Your `if line.text in (♪) then` is no valid Lua syntax.

Something like

`if line.comment or line.text == "" or line.text:find("\u{266A}") then`

Should work.

Comment: was just about to write that, with string.find(line.text, "♪") it works, just tested it, and that should be no difference to your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

In Lua every string have the `string` functions as methods attached.
So use `gsub()` on your string variable in loop like...

```
('Text with ♪ sign in text'):gsub('(♪)','note')
```

...thats replace the sign and output is...

```
Text with note sign in text
```

...instead of replacing it with 'note' an empty '' deletes it.
`gsub()` is returning 2 values.
First: The string with or without changes
Second: A number that tells how often the pattern matches
So second return value can be used for conditions or success.
( 0 stands for "pattern not found" )
So lets check above with...

```
local str,rc=('Text with strange ♪ sign in text'):gsub('(♪)','notation')

if rc~=0 then
 print('Replaced ',rc,'times, changed to: ',str)
end

-- output
-- Replaced     1   times, changed to:  Text with strange notation sign in text
```

And finally only detect, no change made...

```
local str,rc=('Text with strange ♪ sign in text'):gsub('(♪)','%1')

if rc~=0 then 
 print('Found ',rc,'times, Text is: ',str)
end
-- output is...
-- Found    1   times, Text is:     Text with strange ♪ sign in text
```

The `%1` holds what `'(♪)'` found.
So `♪` is replaced with `♪`.
And only `rc` is used as a condition for further handling.